# How to open a local disk file with JavaScript and check whether it has the word which we needed?

Tags: javascript

I want to open text or word file in JavaScript.
After that I want my program to scan that whether it has the word which i needed.
If it has the world then it should produce an alert as word is found,else alert as word is not found.
Please help me in this.
I wrote an code to read from file.But I'm not sure where the content of file is stored and where to use search function.

My current code is

```
<h1>File reader</h1>
<div>
    Select a text file: 
    <input type="file" id="fileInput">
    <pre id="displayArea"><pre>
</div>

window.onload = function() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    var displayArea= document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');

    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        var textType = /text.*/;

        if (file.type.match(textType)) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                displayArea.innerText = reader.result;
            }
    reader.readAsText(file);                

        } else {
            displayArea.innerText = "File not supported!"
        }
  });
}
```

by using this I can get my file content in output,But I need output as an alert whether file has the needed word.

Comment: Tried [`string.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)?

Comment: `=reader.result.match("Hello")`

Comment: @dandavis  `match()` expects a regular expression as parameter.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider:  Showing my age... Strings are simpler/faster if you don't need "wildcards". `"".includes` is the newer way, and `/Hello/.test(str)` is good for RegExp boolean returns. OP's got options...

Comment: Thanks for reply @GeraldSchneider string.indexOf() is not give the result I needed. It always throws -1.

Comment: I just want to copy all the contents local file(either txt or word document) into a variable. After that I want to search that variable for the word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing nothing with your result, thats why you have to store the `reader.result` output in a variable, then look if the word you are looking for is inside of that output and show the alert.

Something like this...

```
var readResult = reader.result;

if (/Hello/.test(readResult)) {
  alert("The word exist");
} else {
  alert("The word does not exist");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is perfectly works. I also tried the same. But Instead of storing reader.result into variable I stored reader.readAsText(file);